# No mapping with AutoMapper with KeyValuePair<K, V>

Tags: .net, generics, automapper, automapper-3

I'm building a generic pretty-print method. One of the special types that I want to handle separately is `KeyValuePair<TK,TV>`. In order to reduce the object to a known type, I thought I would map each `KeyValuePair<TK,TV>` to a `KeyValuePair<object, object>`.

The following code always produces 2 nulls in the `Key`, `Value` properties of `proxy`.

```
Mapper.CreateMap(o.GetType(), typeof(KeyValuePair<object, object>));
var proxy = Mapper.Map<KeyValuePair<object, object>>(o);
```

This non-generic version, on the other hand, works as expected:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(o.GetType(), typeof(DictionaryEntry));
var proxy = Mapper.Map<DictionaryEntry>(o);
```

**Why?**

`o` at this stage has been tested to be a `KeyValuePair<,>`.
I'm using AutoMapper 3.2.1.0 on .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DictionaryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry(v=vs.110).aspx)'s `Key` and `Value` are both settable. When you map to `DictionaryEntry`, AutoMapper matches the `Key` and `Value` property and sets them.

It's unable to do this with [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) since it is immutable. Therefore AutoMapper returns a new `KeyValuePair<object, object>` with the `Key` and `Value` properties unset.

Normally, you could use `ConstructUsing` to get around this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, string>, KeyValuePair<object, object>>()
    .ConstructUsing(kvp => new KeyValuePair<object, object>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
```

However, since you're not using this version of `CreateMap`, this isn't possible.

You could create a simple extension method to do this instead though:

```
public static class KeyValuePairExtensions
{
    public static KeyValuePair<object, object> CastUp<TKey, TValue>(
        this KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<object, object>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

And then use it instead of AutoMapper:

```
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Hello", "World");
KeyValuePair<object, object> proxy = kvp.CastUp();
```

This would prevent you having to create a different mapping definition for every `KeyValuePair` variation you use.

Comment: I see, thanks! Regarding the second part of the answer, that wouldn't be an option as the method this code is in gets the KVP as an `object` reference, i.e. the type parameters are not known.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's unfortunate

Comment: @Mau: Another thing you could do is first map to `DictionaryEntry`, and then map to `KeyValuePair<object, object>`. In that case you could use the `ConstructUsing` method

Comment: When I have a `DictionaryEntry`, then I can just statically build a `KVP<object, object>` :-)